# What is the meaning/role of "into" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

"Pippin cowered back, afraid for a moment, wondering **into** what dreadful country Gandalf was bearing him." - The return of the King.

I think it could be just "wondering what dreadful country..."

I have checked the dictionaries and found nothing about "wonder into"

Could you explain the use of "into" in this context? Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Try to think that sentence physically maybe? Like 'dreadful country Gandalf was bearing him' is a cave. And Pippin is wondering into that cave with a torch in his hand. He is curious and wants to know. Not be mistaken with wander by the way.

Comment: This is the sentence as phrased when one is not trying to end the sentence with a preposition, but the *into* could be put "back" at the end to yield: "*Pippin cowered back, afraid for a moment, wondering what dreadful country Gandalf was bearing him* ***into***."

Comment: Right. Since ending a sentence with a preposition is totally OK for me, this didn't even come to my mind. Good one. Why it is considered wrong I can't understand. They make perfect sense to me.

Comment: @Jim I thought only "which" and "whom" allow the preposition to be placed in front of them. Is it grammatical to actually place preposition in front of "what"?

Comment: @sooeithdk No, this happens with *what*, *where* and *when* too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a literary form of "wondering what dreadful country Gandalf was bearing him into". Give the use of the literary word "bear", that seems quite appropriate.

Comment: @HotLicks - Hmm. Something up with which I do not put.